# Parse SOAP response with namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, soap, xml-parsing, simplexml, xml-namespaces

Any recommendations how to parse this SOAP response and obtain the value of `name` for the `report_type`? Notice there are two instances of name; one under `report_type` and the other under `severity`.

Here is the SOAP response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:getIRResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.icontent.idefense.com/V3/2">
         <ns1:return xsi:type="ns1:IRResponse" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns1:report_type>
               <ns1:id>0</ns1:id>
               <ns1:name>Original Vulnerability</ns1:name>
            </ns1:report_type>
            <ns1:severity>
                <ns1:id>0</ns1:id>
                <ns1:name>HIGH</ns1:name>
            </ns1:severity>
         </ns:return>
      </ns1:getIRResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the PHP code I'm using:

```
<?php        
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);    
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://ws.icontent.idefense.com/V3/2');

    foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns1:report_type/name') as $item)
    {
        echo 'Name: '.$item,'<br>';               
    } 
?>
```

The PHP code doesn't echo anything. When I use `($xml->xpath('//ns1:name') as $item)` it returns both names (Original Vulnerability and HIGH).

I know I'm missing something stupid. Can you help please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why the need to parse XML in the first place? Are you not using the built in SOAP client and sourcing this data via some other means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I've corrected this element

```
</ns:return>
```

and changed it to

```
</ns1:return>
```

I seem to get the result you're after by duplicating the namespace prefix in both xpath segments

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);    
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1','http://ws.icontent.idefense.com/V3/2');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//ns1:report_type/ns1:name') as $item)
{
  echo 'Name: '.$item,'<br>';
}
```

output

```
Name: Original Vulnerability
```